# Make compiled object depend on header file but still use `$^`

Tags: makefile

I have the following `makefile`

```
mybin.a: source1.cpp source2.cpp
   g++ $^ -o $@
```

Now, `source.cpp` includes a header file that I want `mybin.a` to depend on. If I do this:

```
mybin.a: source1.cpp source2.cpp header.hpp
   g++ $^ -o $@
```

Then the header file is needlessly compiled. I know I can do this instead

```
mybin.a: source1.cpp source2.cpp header.hpp
   g++ source1.cpp source2.cpp -o $@
```

But I dislike it because I have to repeat the name of the source files twice. Is there a way to have the best of the two worlds?

Comment: What about reading the [make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) and using the right automatic variable for your problem?

Comment: I see that for my particular example, I can use `$<` which I failed to mention. However, as the updated example shows, this would not work if I have multiple cpp files. I don't see in the documentation a way to handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
mybin.a: source1.cpp source2.cpp header.hpp
    g++ $(filter %.c %.cpp,$^) -o $@
```

Alternatively, you could do things a more standard way:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CLFAGS) $< -o $@

#...

SRCS := source1.cpp source2.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

source1.o : header.hpp

mybin.a: $(OBJS)
     $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```